# sqlite select query top X% for every item

Tags: sqlite, select

i making get topX% query

```
SELECT CAST(ROUNT(COUNT(*) * 0.1)AS INTEGER) FROM person;
```

But syntax error ,,

This is the kind of query I want to finally make.

```
SELECT*FROM person
ORDER BY vote DESC LIMIT (SELECT CAST(ROUNT(COUNT(*) * 0.1)AS INTEGER)
                          FROM person);
```

how to fix it ?

Comment: what's `ROUNT`?

Comment: Is it supposed to be [`round()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#round)?

Comment: @Shawn oh yessss.... :O